# Pass data into a JUnit test class from outside the test class

Tags: java, junit

How do I pass data into a test class I started programmatically with

```
junitCore.run(MyAwesomeClass.class);
```

I need to pass in some objects constructed based on input from the command line. My program is an executable jar.

A little context on why I'm doing this. I'm writing a command line program to drive tests based on inputs from a spreadsheet for my QA guy. I'm trying to test some code that has Android code mixed in, and I want to run it on the JVM. For that, I'm using Robolectric to fill in the stubs just so I can run, but the caveat is, you have to use their JUnit test runner.

Comment: haven't you try [JUnitCore#addListener](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html#addListener(org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener))?

Comment: Yes, the problem is I'm executing the run command from an object that isn't the class where my test lives, so the listener callbacks happen there.

Answer (score 0):

Thing you want is not actually the way JUnit is supposed to be used, because test class should be a complete runnable testing code.

However you can always implement what you want using static initialization prior to running you test class, like:

```
MyAwesomeClass.prepare(myParameter);
junitCore.run(MyAwesomeClass.class);
```

For example:

```
public class Test2 {
    private static int param;
    public static void prepare(int param) {
        Test2.param = param;
    }

    @Test public void test() {
        Assert.assertEquals(param, 2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JUnitCore jUnitCore = new JUnitCore();
        Test2.prepare(2);
        jUnitCore.run(Test2.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by that? How can data been "wiped out"?

Comment: Did you set _static_ fields? JUnit does not nulls all static fields in class. Updated post with working sample.

Comment: I updated my question with a bit more context. The test class is run with RobolectricTestRunner (http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/javadoc/com/xtremelabs/robolectric/RobolectricTestRunner.html)